# How to convert integer to its English representation in Python?

Tags: python, string, integer

I need to convert integers to their English (string) representation in python.
Example:

```
5 = five
20 = twenty
etc.
```

I know, I can use conditions, but I need to convert many integers, so I need the quickest way to achieve it.

Comment: Have you tried anything for yourself yet? We usually help with some *existing* code. You need to show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`pynum2word`](http://pynum2word.sourceforge.net/) can do this for you:

```
>>> import num2word
>>> dir(num2word)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__',
'_lang', '_loc', '_locale', '_locdict', '_module', '_modules',
'n2w', 'n2wmod', 'to_card', 'to_ord', 'to_ordnum', 'to_year']
>>> num2word.to_card(1111)
'one thousand, one hundred and eleven'
```

Comment: Very nice! +1 I was unaware of this.

Comment: How do I install pynum2word? I tried pip, easy_install, and apt-get, none worked. I downloaded the file directly from your link. There's no setup.py. How do I get it to where I can use it?

Comment: @Hoopdady: Yes, very annoyingly `pynum2word` is not available in the Cheeseshop, and in fact isn't even packaged as a `distutils` extension! Very strange! You'll need to download it, extract it, and use it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is probably no library that provides such a functionality

That way to do this is analyze the number, divide it into small numbers and use static lists of defined words
[this](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/10/21/python-converting-numbers-to-words/) article can help you maybe

However if you want to use something different then English, it can get tricky and you'll need to modify the function above

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would try to find a list online of numbers and their corresponding english translation.  A text file would probably be best.  You would then convert that file into a dictionary in python (or save it to a db).  Example {'1': 'one', '2': 'two'...}.  From there, its easy.  I think finding that existing list is the time consuming part, but there has to be one out there.